# Get unique id of computer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, license-key

I need to generate license for each software I distribute in the market. And I will store that license and *computer unique id* in my server database.
So,

1. What is the **Computer's Unique Id** in present?
2. How to get it in **Python-3**

I Googled for it, but most answers I got is taking *MAC Id*, nowdays anyone can change the *MAC Id*.So, **What is the best id that cannot be changed and is visible in *Python-3***

Comment: Can I get comments, why my question is downvoted...?

Comment: Not the downvoter but your question is super broad, super opinionated and frankly seems like just a "give me the code" type of question. The first two are not well fitted for this site and the last one is not well received in this community. Just my thought I guess. Also your first question doesn't make sense, are you asking how to generate a unique id for each computer that wants your software? which is also very opinionated and broad.

Comment: I haven't asked for the full codes...Nor I'm fully depend on it as I have made small research before posting question...I just want to know what will be the unique id that can be visible in python...

Comment: There isn't really a unique id.  Most people try to generate a mostly unique fingerprint, [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858782/how-to-obtain-almost-unique-system-identifier-in-a-cross-platform-way) by examining the machines hardware. Are you targeting just windows machines?  You might be able to use the license id for the OS.

Comment: No, reply to your edit @MooingRawr . I want computer's unique id, not the one created by me...

Comment: Yes @PatrickHaugh , I am just targeting windows machines...

Comment: You are asking 2 questions and the first is a general one that you can be find already answered for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443093/what-is-a-good-unique-pc-identifier

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the question you linked is for C language and I need it for Python-3

Comment: Any updates...?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the unique ID of a Windows Machine, meaning the UUID, here's a simple function to get it:

```
import subprocess
def GetUUID():
    cmd = 'wmic csproduct get uuid'
    uuid = str(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
    pos1 = uuid.find("\\n")+2
    uuid = uuid[pos1:-15]
    return uuid
print(GetUUID())
```

Comment: Is it fixed for all the computers?

Comment: Here's the info on the UUID used by MS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID but the short answer is yes. It's generally what's used within the MS eco-systems for this purpose, so in the code above I just reached into the MS command line to get the UUID from there and pulled it into Python. As long as you just need to run your application on Microsoft Windows machines, this will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of anwsers is so naive and complicated, I googled a lot and I can not get a satisfiying answer. So here is my conclusion:

- for UUID:

  ```
   from wmi import WMI
   from sys import platform

   def get_device_uuid():
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        # linux

    elif platform == "darwin":
        # OS X
    elif platform == "win32":
        return WMI().Win32_ComputerSystemProduct()[0].UUID
  ```
- for device name:

  ```
  def get_device_name():
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        my_system = platform.uname()
        return '{}-{}'.format(my_system.system, my_system.node)
    elif platform == "darwin":
        my_system = platform.uname()
        return '{}-{}'.format(my_system.system, my_system.node)
    elif platform == "win32":
        a = WMI().Win32_ComputerSystemProduct()[0]
        return '{}-{}'.format(a.Manufacturer, a.Name)
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  WMIC tool is being removed now, so this answer is great.